# One google IP address is failing. Is there a way to force a switch to different one?

Tags: dns, ip-address

The Google IP address 74.125.53.100 is failing.  I know no one would believe this so I did an online [ping](http://just-ping.com/index.php):

[image]

As this image shows one of the IP addresses for Google is failing.

However there are others.  If I type them in then I can get to Google just fine.  But when I try to search, Google reverts back to the broken IP.

Is there any way for me to say "I want to do a search with one of the working IP addresses"?

Comment: Or, a quick workaround: add `.nyud.net`, so: http://www.google.com.nyud.net (see http://www.coralcdn.org/ for details)

Comment: Or wait a few minutes, I am not seeing any packet loss from that IP at this time...

Comment: I did wait "a few minutes".  I posted this after an hour of the IP Address being bad.  (Google is so huge that if it does not work, your first suspect should be your computer not google.  I did a lot of checking on my side first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a static resolution in your hosts file pointing google.com to one of the good IPs.

[Host File on Windows](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/hosts.htm)

Comment: Good idea.  Next time it happens this is the route I will try

Answer (score 1):

Mac/Linux hosts file can be found here (if your doing this from a Mac or Linux):

```
/etc/hosts
```

Add this line to the hosts file:

```
74.125.45.100 www.google.com
```

(substituting with the IP you want)